# Replace @odata prefix in OData payload

Tags: rest, web, serialization, odata

I need to customize odata payload json content from e.g.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:49644/v1.0/$metadata#Feeds",
    "@odata.count": 6,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": 1,
```

To

```
{
    "@MyCustomdata.context": "http://localhost:49644/v1.0/$metadata#Feeds",
    "@MyCustomdata.count": 6,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": 1,
```

I use ODataLib http://odata.github.io/odata.net/

tried to use custom ODataResourceSerializer, ODataResourceSetSerializer

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar to this, in my case I needed to remove the '@' prefix to stay compatible with a legacy project.

To fix it I just recompiled `Microsoft.OData.Core` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` from source, then edited `ODataJsonLightWriterUtils.WriteInstanceAnnotationName` to change how the annotation is serialized.

Note that the OData WebApi project uses ODataLib to do its serialization, but you need to compile both so you can include both as custom assemblies instead of their usual nuget packages.

The source for the projects are here:

https://github.com/OData/Webapi/tree/feature/netcore

https://github.com/OData/odata.net

In my case I'm on netcoreapp2.0, ymmv.

There is a setting you can pass into DI to remove the `odata` prefix altogether:

```c#
public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //...
    var odata_options = new ODataSimplifiedOptions(){ EnableWritingODataAnnotationWithoutPrefix = true};
    //...
    app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
    {
        routeBuilder.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count();
        // custom routing - ymmv
        string odata_route_name = "ODataRoute";
        routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute(odata_route_name, "data", a =>
        {
            a.AddService(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => model);
            a.AddService<IODataPathHandler>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => new DefaultODataPathHandler());
            a.AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting(odata_route_name, routeBuilder));
            a.AddService<ODataSerializerProvider>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => new CIQODataSerializerProvider(sp, loggerFactory));
            a.AddService<ODataDeserializerProvider>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => new DefaultODataDeserializerProvider(sp));
            a.AddService<ILoggerFactory>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => loggerFactory);
            a.AddService<ODataSimplifiedOptions>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => odata_options);
            // ... other specifics to my situation
        });
        routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
        // mvc/api routes ...                
    });
}
```

If compiling the source projects gets too much, I also tried https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy to edit the nuget-supplied DLL. I think this will work, you just need to make sure all packages with a dependency on ODataLib are removed so your direct DLL reference is used.